# Social Security vs SSI: cash gifts, free rent, etc. (USA)

Tags: united-states, retirement, gift-tax, rent, social-security

I understand the social security administration may reduce SSI benefits if the recipient receives cash gifts, free rent, etc.  What about normal social security benefits or retirement benefits?  Are those impacted?  I looked all over online and could only find information about SSI.

https://www.ssa.gov/ssi/text-living-ussi.htm

Background: I was interested in gifting my mother $15,000 *or* letting her live in a home I’m purchasing rent free (not both). It’s my understanding, that should not have tax implications in most situations.  Even still, I’m concerned it could impact her social security.

Comment: SSI is different than regular Social Security. It's basically a welfare program, with payments based on need.  Regular SS is a government pension: the amount you get depends only on how much you paid into the system (via a fairly complex formula): you could be Warren Buffett and still collect Social Security.  (I think he actually does...)  The only means-based difference is that people with higher incomes will pay income tax on part of their benefit.

Answer (score 4):

**You're fine.**

SS retirement (or spouse or survivor) benefit is not directly reduced or affected by other income with the single exception of certain government pensions, nor ever by assets. However, if you have other taxable income above a low limit it makes some (or more) of your SS benefit subject to income tax, which reduces the benefit you keep without reducing the nominal payment (unless you elect to have withholding). Cash gifts or free rent/housing are not taxable income to the recipient (except some housing provided by an *employer*).

If someone is on Medicare including part B and/or D, or an Advantage plan that has B or D equivalent premiums, which many though not all
SS retirees are, and has fairly high income, it increases the part B and/or D premiums -- and at least the part B premium is usually but not always deducted  from the SS benefit payment. This is also based on tax return data with a modification which still omits gifts and housing, and delayed 2 years.